# Create a report for a form javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, report

Hope someone can help.

I have a dynamically generated form that ends up looking like this

```
             <form>
              <header><h2 id="title">This is a Survey Title</h2></header>
              <ul class="Question_list">
                <li class="question">
                  <div id="sm_survey_question_0">
                    <fieldset>
                      <div class="question_text">is this a test?</div>
                      <input type="radio" name="0" value="1">yes<br>
                      <input type="radio" name="0" value="2">no<br>
                      <input type="radio" name="0" value="3">maybe<br>
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="question">
                  <div id="sm_survey_question_1">
                    <fieldset>
                      <div class="question_text">Is Batman the best?</div>
                      <input type="radio" name="1" value="1">yes<br>
                      <input type="radio" name="1" value="2">no<br>
                    </fieldset>
                  </div></li>
                <li>
                <div id="sm_survey_question_2">
                  <fieldset>
                    <div class="question_text">best colors</div>
                    <input type="radio" name="2" value="1">red<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="2" value="2">blue<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="2" value="3">green<br>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </form>
```

and I would like that when the submit button is clicked i can generate a "report",  a string would work with the question and the answers selected. 
I cant wrap my mind around how to do that.

so far im able to cycle through the questions, check what answers are checked but its the end when i have to create a sting with the questions + its checked

```
      module.createReport = function() {
                console.log('reporting');
                var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
                console.log(questions.length+1,"questions");
                var StringAnswers="";
                for (var i = questions.length ; i >= 0; i--) {
                 var textq= document.getElementById('sm_survey_question_'+i).getElementsByClassName("question_text")[0].innerHTML;
                 var answers = document.getElementById('sm_survey_question_'+i).getElementsByTagName('input');
                 for (var j = answers.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                   if (answers[j].checked) {
                    var isanswerC= answers[j].value;
                   };
                   var conc= textq+" "+isanswerC;
                   StringAnswers.concat(conc);
                 };
                };
                  console.log(conc);

              };
```

Comment: Please help yourself first and at least try writing some code. The only line you're showing could already be good for beginning, just go further and come back here with your code, problem description, etc if you get stuck.

Comment: yes, i updated it with my progress thanks.

Comment: Well it looks like you're almost there buddy ! What exactly keeps you going further ? Do you get any error ? I would suggest creating a jsfiddle with your code.